# How to access online mysql database in android?

Tags: java, android, mysql

I have created an online database about the restaurants and I need to access this database through my android application, so that I can display the data to the users after filtering. My application does not need to update the database, but my problem is how to connect to my online mysql database and provide it to the users? I have looked on many suggestions on this site as well as on others, and I just found I have to use JSON parser while accessing but do not how to do it.

Comment: You'd better use a webservice platform that will call your database. Don't call the database directly with your application.

Comment: @tsabz yeah, which web service will be the best?

Comment: It's up to you to develop it. As Nanne said, a RESTful API would be the best. You can check on google for a sipmle ways to do it with php for example.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The best solution is provide a public API, managed for example with PHP, which delivers your database data filtered and displayed as your Android application needs.

Comment: A great example of a method to provide an API would be a REST-full api. the OP can read up on that for instance

Comment: @Stefano Ortisi how can I use public API

Comment: You have to develop, as @tsabz said,  your public API.

Answer (score 4):

This link might help you . http://www.androidhive.info/2012/01/android-login-and-registration-with-php-mysql-and-sqlite/
Just get an understanding of JSON parsers and how it can be used in android for retrieving data from database on server... you can write webservices in php..

Answer (score 0):

You need to provide a server side solution that the Android application can speak to. PHP scripts are a good way to go, that can directly interface with the MySQL database, and return results to the device.

You can then be creative with the PHP script, by sorting the results etc, and providing a more comprehensive solution by taking away some of the processing from the Android device, and doing it server side where battery life isn't as much of a problem.

You simply need to implement web service calls on the Android device, simple GET/POST requests over HTTP suffice depending on what you intend to do. Have a look into REST APIs for guidelines on how to implement properly.

You can easily add a PHP script to the same server as the MySQL database for this