# Can an Android App connect directly to an online mysql database

Tags: android, mysql

```
Android 3.3 API 18
```

Hello,

I am developing my first App using android. The App will have to connect to an online database to store user data.

I am looking for a cloud storage with a MySQL database included. However, can my App connect directly to this MySQL database and push and pull data from it? Or is there other things I need to do?

Many thanks for any suggestions,

Comment: yes u can u need to write server side code for that either in php or .net

Comment: I think this may help full for you

[See this post]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11324939/how-to-access-online-mysql-database-in-android

Comment: http://androidbash.com/connecting-android-app-to-a-database-using-php-and-mysql/        Here the data is being populated from backend database.

Answer (score 86, accepted):

Yes you can do that.

Materials you need:

1. WebServer
2. A Database Stored in the webserver
3. And a little bit android knowledge :)
4. Webservices (json ,Xml...etc) whatever you are comfortable with

**1.** First set the internet permissions in your manifest file

```
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

**2.** Make a class to make an HTTPRequest from the server 
(i am using json parisng to get the values)

for eg:

```
    public class JSONfunctions {

    public static JSONObject getJSONfromURL(String url) {
        InputStream is = null;
        String result = "";
        JSONObject jArray = null;

        // Download JSON data from URL
        try {
            HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(url);
            HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
            HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
            is = entity.getContent();

        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("log_tag", "Error in http connection " + e.toString());
        }

        // Convert response to string
        try {
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                    is, "iso-8859-1"), 8);
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            String line = null;
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                sb.append(line + "\n");
            }
            is.close();
            result = sb.toString();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("log_tag", "Error converting result " + e.toString());
        }

        try {

            jArray = new JSONObject(result);
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            Log.e("log_tag", "Error parsing data " + e.toString());
        }

        return jArray;
    }
}
```

**3.** In your `MainActivity` Make an object of the class `JsonFunctions` and pass the url as an argument from where you want to get the data

eg:

```
JSONObject jsonobject;
```

`jsonobject = JSONfunctions.getJSONfromURL("http://YOUR_DATABASE_URL");`

**4.** And then finally read the jsontags and store the values in an arraylist and later show it in listview if you want

and if you have any problem you can follow this blog
he gives excellent android tutorials [AndroidHive](http://www.androidhive.info/2012/05/how-to-connect-android-with-php-mysql/)

Since the above answer i wrote was long back and now `HttpClient`, `HttpPost`,`HttpEntity` have been removed in Api 23. You can use the below code in the build.gradle(app-level) to still continue using `org.apache.http`in your project.

```
android {
    useLibrary 'org.apache.http.legacy'
    signingConfigs {}
    buildTypes {}
}
```

or You can use `HttpURLConnection` like below to get your response from server

```
public String getJSON(String url, int timeout) {
HttpURLConnection c = null;
try {
    URL u = new URL(url);
    c = (HttpURLConnection) u.openConnection();
    c.setRequestMethod("GET");
    c.setRequestProperty("Content-length", "0");
    c.setUseCaches(false);
    c.setAllowUserInteraction(false);
    c.setConnectTimeout(timeout);
    c.setReadTimeout(timeout);
    c.connect();
    int status = c.getResponseCode();

    switch (status) {
        case 200:
        case 201:
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(c.getInputStream()));
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            String line;
            while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
                sb.append(line+"\n");
            }
            br.close();
            return sb.toString();
    }

} catch (MalformedURLException ex) {
    Logger.getLogger(getClass().getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
} catch (IOException ex) {
    Logger.getLogger(getClass().getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
} finally {
   if (c != null) {
      try {
          c.disconnect();
      } catch (Exception ex) {
         Logger.getLogger(getClass().getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
      }
   }
}
return null;
```

}

or You can use 3rd party Library like `Volley`, `Retrofit` to call the webservice api and get the response and later parse it with using `FasterXML-jackson`, `google-gson`.

Comment: Thanks for your solution. Just wondering if you could recommend any hosting sites that are free that have MySQL database that my App can connect to. As this academic I don't much bandwidth of space. Thanks.

Comment: I am a beginer to android a well. Wont we have to create a local database inorder fr the app to fuction smoothly later on? I am working on a similar project. It works fine till we are connected to the internet but after that it wont. Does that make sence?

Comment: Even though there is a solution, the correct answer to "Can an Android App connect directly to an online mysql database" is NO.

Comment: If you are using a web server, you indeed answer the question's situation, but then it is not "directly".

Comment: @BrainCrash if you write a library that implements the MySQL protocol directly, it is still technically possible as long as you have access to the `java.net` classes. It may be more complicated than adding JDBC dependency directly, but the answer is certainly not "no".

Comment: Here i got one tutorial and data is being populated from backend database. http://androidbash.com/connecting-android-app-to-a-database-using-php-and-mysql/

Answer (score 12):

What you want to do is a bad idea. It would require you to embed your username and password in the app. This is a very bad idea as it might be possible to reverse engineer your APK and get the username and password to this publicly facing mysql server which may contain sensitive user data.

I would suggest making a web service to act as a proxy to the mysql server. I assume users need to be logged in, so you could use their username/password to authenticate to the web service.

Comment: what one can do is different from what one should do.  you are absolutely correct in your concerns.  exposing username and password are an issue, but an online push pull service without certification can be just as harmful (especially if decompilation also exposes data schemas).

Answer (score 8):

You can use PHP, JSP, ASP or any other server side script to connect with mysql database and and return JSON data that you can parse it to in your android app [this link how to do it](http://www.androidhive.info/2012/05/how-to-connect-android-with-php-mysql/)

Answer (score 5):

step 1 : make a web service on your server

step 2 : make your application make a call to the web service and receive result sets

Answer (score 4):

Yes definitely you can connect to the MySql online database for that you need to create a web service. This web service will provide you access to the MySql database. Then you can easily pull and push data to MySql Database. PHP will be a good option for creating web service its simple to implement. Good luck...

Answer (score 4):

you can definitely make such application, you need to make http conection to the database, by calling a php script which will in response run specific queries according to your project, and generated the result in the form of xml, or json formate , whihc can be displayed on your android application!.
for complete tutorial on [how to connect android application to mysql](http://www.trustingeeks.com/connect-android-app-to-mysql-database/) i would recommend to check out this tutorila

Answer (score 3):

It is actually very easy. But there is no way you can achieve it directly. You need to select a service side technology. You can use anything for this part. And this is what we call a RESTful API or a SOAP API. It depends on you what to select. 
I have done many project with both. I would prefer REST. 
So what will happen you will have some scripts in your web server, and you know the URLs. For example we need to make a user registration. And for this we have

**mydomain.com/v1/userregister.php**

Now from the android side you will send an HTTP request to the above URL. And the above URL will handle the User Registration and will give you a response that whether the operation succeed or not.

For a complete detailed explanation of the above concept. You can visit the following link.

**[**Android MySQL Tutorial to Perform CRUD Operation](https://www.simplifiedcoding.net/android-mysql-tutorial-to-perform-basic-crud-operation/)****

Answer (score 2):

Look at this online backend.

[Parse.com](https://www.parse.com/)

They offer push notifications, social integration, data storage, and the ability to add rich custom logic to your app’s backend with Cloud Code.