# Using local database with Android virtual device

Tags: android, database, connection, localhost, android-virtual-device

Following this topic [Can an Android App connect directly to an online mysql database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19217835/can-an-android-app-connect-directly-to-an-online-mysql-database) I'm trying to approach Android and Database on my studies; The things is, I would like to know if I can or may use a local database based on USBWebserver to connect it through the app inside AVD?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please follow this simple tutorial [here](http://www.androidhive.info/2012/05/how-to-connect-android-with-php-mysql/)

Comment: Seems not that simple but at least legit ;) I will give it a try, thanks.

Comment: if this answer is useful then please rate it up.