# Linking between php and android using json

Tags: php, android, json, api, doctrine

I am working on an android app and I am using php/doctrine to retrive the data from the database. I put said data in a json object.

The problem is that I do not know how to display it on the android. 
This is the php code:

```
function getTransaction($id) {
  $transaction = $this->getDoctrine()
    ->getRepository('nameBundle:Transaction')
    ->find($id);
  if(!$transaction) {
    throw $this->createNotFoundException('No transaction found'.$id);
  }

  $array = $transaction->toArray();
  $json = json_encode($array);
}
```

Comment: Check my already answer [here][1] You can implement by this example.


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/a/22558535/3360307

Comment: http://www.androidhive.info/2012/05/how-to-connect-android-with-php-mysql/

Comment: Basically this tutorial is what you want. Saves you one click http://www.androidhive.info/2012/05/how-to-connect-android-with-php-mysql/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please follow this simple tutorial [here](http://www.androidhive.info/2012/05/how-to-connect-android-with-php-mysql/)

Answer (score 0):

1. You have to deploy your php code in server.
2. Assume you have url (http://xxxx.com/getJson.php) which return json
3. Create HttpClient and make a call.
4. get json data and parse the response and display.

More details Check this [Read Json From url](http://hmkcode.com/android-parsing-json-data/)

Answer (score 0):

You have to get first the request httpPost of the server.

```
protected Boolean doInBackground(String... params){

    boolean resul = true;

    HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();

HttpPost post = new
         HttpPost("http://example/getinfo.php");

post.setHeader("content-type", "application/json");}
```

And then parse the json object.

```
try{
    //Build the json object
    JSONObject dataJson = new JSONObject();


    dataJson.put("lastName", params[0]);
    dataJson.put("phoneNumer", Integer.parseInt(params[1]));

    StringEntity entity = new StringEntity(dataJson.toString());
    post.setEntity(entity);

        HttpResponse resp = httpClient.execute(post);
        String respStr = EntityUtils.toString(resp.getEntity());

        if(!respStr.equals("true"))
            resul = false;
    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {
        Log.e("Rest","Error", ex);
        resul = false;
    }

    return resul;
```