# Sending data from android to php using http

Tags: java, php, android, http

This my android code I used to send to my php file in website. also modified android manifest file.

```
        ArrayList<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(7);
        nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("number", "5556"));
        nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("password",password));
        nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("token",token));

        HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://futuretime.in/post.php");
        httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));
        HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
```

This is my php script for receiving data from android.
But my problem is when I printed data in php it is not showing any value.

```
        <?php 
          $number= $_POST['number'];
          $password = $_POST['password'];
          $token   = $_POST['token'];
          echo $number;
        ?>
```

Comment: what is your question? are you getting any error?

Comment: What exact you want to do???

Comment: You can send data by JSON parsing. Small reference is  http://stackoverflow.com/a/22686616/3360307

Comment: You cannot echo data in php while calling from client side, save that data somewhere when called from android and then see if it's received or not

Comment: if (!empty($_POST)) {$number= $_POST['number'];
          $password = $_POST['password'];
          $token   = $_POST['token'];
          echo $number;}else{echo "Empty";} try this and check your post is empty or not. then you can identify where is the error.

Comment: @Sunny no errors but the data is not receiving in php I thinks so because when i print received data it is not displaying

Comment: @anuruddhika  it is saying empty not receiving data

Comment: did u get the answer? as Himani Agarwal mentioned you can use json parser for this.

Comment: @anuruddhika no, i am getting a message like: org.apache.http.message.basichttpresponse 4fb06e5e

Answer (score 1):

you can try use Ion https://github.com/koush/ion ,is a great library for make http request.
is a simple example .check the project site for more examples and wiki.

```
    Ion.with(getContext(), "https://koush.clockworkmod.com/test/echo")
   .setBodyParameter("goop", "noop")
   .setBodyParameter("foo", "bar")
   .asString()
   .setCallback(...)
```