# Connect Android to local mysql database via API

Tags: android, mysql, apache

I am currently storing my Android data in **Firebase** and 
I want to change the structure in order to save the incoming data from the Android app in an SQL database in my local computer. I have read several solutions about how to expose a Mysql database publicly, but not much about security issues.

**My questions are:**

1) What it is better in order to make these Android-Mysql connections secure, Apache or SSH?

2) Are there any APIs in order not to have to configure these connections manually?

Answer (score 0):

Kindly refer to the link below.Your question is quite similar the one discussed in it [How to connect android to mysql database securely](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36249157/how-to-connect-android-to-mysql-database-securely)