# How to make QR code scanner app on Android, extract information from QR Code, filter it and add to mysql db

Tags: android, mysql, qr-code

Can somebody tell me how to make QR code scanner app on Android, extract information from QR Code, filter it and add to mysql db from the app?
because I'm kind of hurry to making the app
thanks!

Comment: Stack Overflow is not a code writing service, it's expected that you attempt to code this yourself. I would suggest you do some research on your issue (maybe try the search box at the top of the page) and make an attempt at writing some code yourself. If/when you come across any issues with your code ask again and explain what you have tried, and why it did not work for you. See [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) for help with asking a great question as well as [Minimum, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Ok, thanks for advising me

Answer (score 0):

For qr code scanning you would require a third party library like "zxing". Here are some useful links for zxing and mysql integration:

[Integrate ZXing in Android Studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18543668/integrate-zxing-in-android-studio)

[Can an Android App connect directly to an online mysql database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19217835/can-an-android-app-connect-directly-to-an-online-mysql-database)