# Android - send / receive data to online mysql database

Tags: java, android

I have an edit text and a button when the user type for example the word "hi"

I want to make when he clicks on the button the following steps

- get the word in the edit text send it to mysql online database
- on the database I will be having many conditions if the word is for example "hi it will send "hello" .. if "how are you" I'll send "good"
- the the app receive the new string and print it.

what can i do is getting the text from the edit text and printing it
but how to send a certain value to online mysql database and if it is equal to the stored value it receive another value ?

Comment: you can achieve  using service or API

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can an Android App connect directly to an online mysql database](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19217835/can-an-android-app-connect-directly-to-an-online-mysql-database)

Answer (score 1):

What you are asking is very basic , a little try and you can do it yourself. Basically you need to take values from your EditText fields using getText method, then you will call a php , other server end api to send these values to your server using get or post  methods .
Refer this link for more help [this link](http://www.androidhive.info/2012/05/how-to-connect-android-with-php-mysql/)