# How to make android connect directly to mysql

Tags: java, android, mysql

I want to use android built-in java.sql to drive html: https://developer.android.com/reference/java/sql/package-summary,
But there is no way to access
My code:

```
    public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private static final String DB_URL = "jdbc:mysql://127.0.0.1/pcDB";
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        String query = "SELECT * FROM gpstable";
        try {
            Class.forName("java.sql.Driver");
            Connection connection = DriverManager.getConnection(DB_URL,"koer3740","password");

            Toast.makeText(this,"Successful Connection",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

In addition, according to this teaching html: http://seotoolzz.com/android/android-dynamic-listview-mysql-jdbc.php, using the external jdbc, found that DriverManager.class is not in jdbc

My English is not good, sorry.

Comment: why are you writing database code in your android app ?

Comment: Hi...Android provides SQLite already, why are you trying to use MySQL?

Comment: you can use this code:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19217835/can-an-android-app-connect-directly-to-an-online-mysql-database

Comment: I have huge data in mysql, sqlite can't meet my needs.

Comment: If you want to use MySql, you have to developpe an api (REST for example ) between your app and server to handle requests (using Volley API for example)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although it is not recommended for Android to connect with mysql directly, you can possibly do so. I actually found another stack overflow link that explains why it is not recommended (in first answer) and also gives answer of your original query (in second answer). Please have a look:

[Can we connect remote MySQL database in Android using JDBC?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26470117/can-we-connect-remote-mysql-database-in-android-using-jdbc)