# How to connect android studio (developing mobile apps) with phpmyadmin database in a server?

Tags: javascript, java, mysql, android-studio, phpmyadmin

I'm actually a beginner in developing mobile apps. For now, I'm using android studio to create an app. So, I have to connect the app with database (phpmyadmin/MySQL) in the server as we want a centralized database that can be use for the website as well as mobile app. So how can I connect it? I really don't have any idea on how to do this.

Comment: There are plenty of articles on the internet on this subject.
Here is just one of them: https://www.skysilk.com/blog/2018/how-to-connect-an-android-app-to-a-mysql-database/

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can an Android App connect directly to an online mysql database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19217835/can-an-android-app-connect-directly-to-an-online-mysql-database)