# What SQL databases are used in Android to build a simple app with a login system?

Tags: android, mysql

I'm trying to build an Android app where the database is on the server side.I hear that SQLite is a local database so it doesn't really work for what I'm trying to do.

In java I would use JDBC to connect to MySQL and send requests normally.
In PHP too it's almost the same thing.

The app needs a login system and all of that...
How can I do this in Android ?

Comment: Write your PHP or JAVA server based code as an API

Comment: Take a look at Firebase, among other services it has a login system and a NoSQL database. If certain quotas are not exceeded, it is free

Answer (score 0):

[Android does not support MySQL out of the box](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15733041/16279195), but you can [implement it](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19218578/16279195).

Probably the SQLite you heard about, in the Android environment, refers to [Room](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/room), the standard to save persistent data locally on the device.

In the mobile world, often a good option (if they fits for you) are NoSQL databases. There are plenty, hosted services like [Firebase](https://firebase.google.com/), [DynamoDB](https://aws.amazon.com/dynamodb/) or open source like [MongoDB](https://www.mongodb.com/), [Supabase](https://supabase.com/).